# How to set color of the text in a cell programatically

Tags: react-data-grid

Is is possible to set color of the text in a cell programmatically?
Well my scenario is i have some numbers filling in the data-grid. I want to color them according to their values. I'm kind of lost here because i didn't found a way to customize a single cell. I've tried the 'rowRender' but it doesn't accomplish my task since it only colors a row. What i want is to color a single cell.
Is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can format the column according to the data. Please see the following example to understand how to achieve it,

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import "./styles.css";
class NameFormatter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span className={this.props.dependentValues.id === 1 ? "red" : "green"}>
        {this.props.value}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
let columns = [
  {
    key: "id",
    name: "Id",
    getRowMetaData: row => row
  },
  {
    key: "name",
    name: "Name",
    getRowMetaData: row => row,
    formatter: NameFormatter
  }
];
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [{ id: 1, name: "einsten" }, { id: 2, name: "newton" }]
    };
    this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);
    this.getSize = this.getSize.bind(this);
  }
  rowGetter(rowIndex) {
    let rows = this.getRows();
    return rows[rowIndex];
  }
  getRows() {
    return this.state.data;
  }
  getSize() {
    return this.getRows().length;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rowsCount={this.getSize()}
        rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
      />
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Inorder to customize the column we need to write a formatter component,here `Nameformatter` is the formatter component for the `name` column .We can access the column value via `this.props.value` and the meta data(Other column values) through `this.props.dependentValues.nameoffield` in the formatter component.

See the working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q3y7v69p6)

Comment: @NimeshaKalinga Sorry i didn't understand your requirements.Please elaborate

Comment: Oh, nevermind, that was my bad, i could access the data from the props, i accept your answer, thanks

Comment: This is the best answer out there!